# Win32 Edit printing incorrect characters

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi

I am using a Win32 edit to display debugging information, and I have placed the edit, along with the rest of my basic GUI in a class. But when I output anything to the edit it displays '??????????????????????????'. I think the error lies in my `MyGUI::append(LPCSTR)` method, although it has always worked perfectly in the past. Any comments/ideas/solutions will be appreciated. If I need to post all the code pertaining to my GUI class please let me know so.

My class lies in the namespace `Interface`, along with the stand-alone `WindowProcedure` function, which I call when registering the application with the `WNDCLASSEX` object.

The win32 edit is not created in the `WM_CREATE` handle within the `WindowProcedure`(as it probably should be) as I could not place the function inside my GUI class.

Method that creates the edit:

```
HWND createEdit( HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hwnd, int appBott, int appTop ){
    return CreateWindowEx(  WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
                            TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""),
                            WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | ES_MULTILINE| WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL,
                            10, 10, appBott-25, appTop-50,
                            hwnd,
                            (HMENU) 102,
                            hInst,
                            NULL );
}
```

Used in 'guiCreate()' method as:
    HWND hEdit = createEdit( hInst, hWin, appWidth, appHeight );

Method that displays text in edit:

```
void Interface::MyGUI::append( LPCSTR text ){
    if( created && !stopAll ){
        int TextLen = SendMessage(hEdit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
        SendMessageW(hEdit, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)TextLen, (LPARAM)TextLen);
        SendMessageW(hEdit, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM) text);
    }
}
```

Used in main program as:

```
MyGUI form(); //initialize form
form.append( (LPCSTR)"Example text\n" );
```

Input text: 'Example text.\n'
Displayed text: '?????????????? l'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting ANSI it would seem. In that case, don't call `SendMessageW`, call `SendMessageA` or even `SendMessage` and let that be expanded to `SendMessageA`.

You call `SendMessageW` but pass ANSI encoded text. When you called `SendMessageW` you promised to send UTF-16 encoded text.

However, you should stop targeting ANSI I think. Target Unicode instead. Stop using the `TEXT()` macro and use the `L` prefix for your string literals. And stop casting string types. That `(LPCSTR)` cast is asking for trouble. When you cast like that you tell the compiler that you know better than it does. And usually that is not the case.

Comment: @searchnot Glad that helped. You are able to accept answers, even with low rep, FWIW.